# CoqIDE and JAVA

Tags: coq, coqide

I want to retrieve the result of the compilation of a file. v from coqide or coqc for treated with java, rather I have treatment of an automaton and I want to build a graphical interface of this automaton in java.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This project about connecting Coq to Eclipse might of of some help: [Coqoon](http://itu.dk/research/tomeso/coqoon)

It is specifically about Java verification and takes special care of managing `.v` files.